# What's '-ensorflow'?I can't uninstall it

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

When I use cmd 'pip list',I find a package called '**-ensorflow**' which couldn't be unistalled using command 'pip uninstall'.Its version is **'1.9.0'** .
I have installed '**tensorflow 1.13.1**',what's the difference between them? What's more, when I upgraded 'tensorflow' from 1.09 to 1.13,CMD seemed to show version conficts between **'-ensorflow'** and **'tensorboard'**.

Running Windows 10, Python 3.7.1.

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas. Thanks in advance.

package list

[image]

using command 'pip uninstall'

[image]

Comment: Try using quotes around "-ensorflow" when attempting to perform the pip uninstall.  In your example, pip is interpreting the "-e" as an option, with an argument of "nsorflow".  Naturally, this doesn't work, since there is no "-e" option.

Comment: @JamCon Quotes do not change a thing because they are meant to protect shell special characters, and "-" is not a special shell character.

Comment: Try `pip uninstall -- -ensorflow`.

Comment: @DYZ  I tried to ues ''pip uninstall -- -ensorflow',but CMD  still shows Invalid requirement: '-ensorflow'

Comment: Any good on this matter? Came across with the very same issue with a custom lib.

Answer (score 4):

I found an answer to this. There must be some issues when you are uninstalling the package. If you search your folders (C:\Anaconda3\envs\ml-agents\Lib\site-packages for me) you will find the folder "~ensorflow-gpu" and another dist folder with similar. Just delete the folder and then restart the console. No error will come